# Re-Fill Form after redirect

Tags: php, forms, validation, redirect

I'm a beginner in PHP trying implementing a simple registration system for a website. The login form processing is done in a special file, where if there were empty or invalid data submitted (email and password) I redirect the user to the main page (the same with the login form) with a special query to handle the error and create a message.

The problem is: the form is empty again. If the user just forgot one field, I'd like to fill the other field automatically. How can I implement this feature? Pass the existing field also in a query? I'd like to avoid doing this, but not sure if it is possible to pass in another way (POST or something like).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why are you posting values on a seperate file and then redirecting. just post the values directly on the same page where the login form is and there you can handle it very easily with  conditions of matched or not matched.

Comment: agree. submit the file to itself. if the data is valid, redirect. if the data is not valid, simply continue printing the original page, using the POST vars to re-fill in the form. Just beware of XSS vulnerabilities. another option would be to use AJAX to submit the form, then redirect with JS on success, otherwise, your form is already filled out and you just have to add an error message to the page with JS. JS would of course require graceful degradation unless you plan on making JS a requirement for your site.

Comment: The page that shows the form is the main page, with the little login box. So I thought it would be better to handle it separately. But yeah, that's an idea, thanks. Anyway, how will I re-fill the form once I have the variables in hand?

Comment: Thanks @dqhendricks , AJAX was initially in the plans, but seems to be too much at this moment. I'll certainly consider including it in the future, but would like to keep it simple now.

Comment: @winck you could still separate most of your PHP from your HTML even though they both happen on the same request. MVC pattern is the generally used way.

Comment: check if values are posted and put them in vlue attribute of input tag

Comment: @RaghavBhushan Ah, of course! Sorry, sounds obvious but this didn't come in my mind. Thanks again.